# Git subprojects for Laravel app

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5

How can I setup groups of controller/views/models as separate Git repos but use them in a single Laravel app?

For example, I want to keep everything related to users in a separate Git repo. That means the user controller, the user model, the user views, the user routes, so whenever I make an update to the users functionality, other Laravel projects that also use this would get the updates by just pulling.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as a git submodule.

That is, to make a folder structure for example:

```
App
 /Users - first submodule
   /Model
   /Controller
   /View
 /Post - second submodule
   /Model
   /Controller
   /View
...
```

Comment: Does this require any config changes in the parent project? Or will it find the submodules on its own?

Comment: try http://apiato.io/ there already been implemented. You do not need to change the configuration, the main thing to keep the namespace and extends the right thing